# parameter for getting body content of drupal node

Tags: 7, services

I'm using Services module for rest services.

When i am passing this url

```
    $base_url/rest/node?fields=title,nid&parameters[nid]=18
```

I got this result

```
       <result is_array="true">
          <item>
             <title>Speed alert</title>
             <nid>18</nid>
             <uri>http://localhost/xxz/drupal/rest/node/18</uri>
          </item>
       </result>
```

Now, Is there any parameter like(body or content ..) to retrieve only body content of the perticular node(i.e node/18) via rest.

Comment: Try just `fields=field_body` in your URL.

Comment: Hey tyler it's not working for me . It gave same output like i mentioned above. Some cases it gives error                  SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't.field_body' in 'field list'"]

Comment: It may be that the default node index service resource only includes `base` fields. You can use hooks to add stuff to the results: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/services/tree/docs/services.alter.api.php?h=7.x-3.x - I've done something similar in this module: http://cgit.drupalcode.org/drupalgap/tree/drupalgap.module